# Tomcat6 as a Windows service doesnt recognize mapped drive

Tags: tomcat, windows-xp, tomcat6

I have a directory on my C drive as `C:/ABCD/XYZ`, this directory I have mapped as D drive. `XYZ` contains other several sub-directories viz. `dir1`, `dir2` etc.
I have Tomcat 6 installed as a service on Windows XP.
When I run my servlet which has code viz.

```
(new File("D:\dir1")).isDirectory();
```

This above line of code returns the value as `false`

The exact same line of code returns `true` if I start Tomcat 6 through command line(this tomcat is extracted from the zip file).
I realize that this issue is due to the user(Windows and/or Tomcat) and its permissions but I can't figure out exactly what the issue is and how to resolve it.
Can anyone please shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to realize that the network mapping that you do when you're logged in happens in your user's context. A service typically runs in its own context and doesn't have the same mapping as arbitrary users. (Imagine two users having accounts on the machine: Both can have different drive mappings - which one should the service take?)

I'm not working with windows for a while, so I'll rely on you finding the information yourself on how to map drives for services - or on others to point out the actual location. Hope this quick answer helps at least to understand the underlying problem

Comment: Some food for thought. Gives me a bit of new direction. Thanks.